# New To HTML/CSS Can't Get Divs In Header To Stay In Place And Keep Aspect Ratio With Window Resize

Tags: html, css

First of all, I apologise if most of this code is messed up. I've been trying to solve this problem and have made a number of adjustments without really knowing what I'm doing.

I'm totally new to html and CSS. I'm attempting to make a header, everything looks fine until I try to decrease the window size.

I wanted 2 images either side of the title. I made a div within the main container (.banner) div, and put the two separate images in there too.

As soon as I decrease the width the whole thing begins to squish down, the photos loose their width until they go distorted (they seem to keep their height), the main title text and the text below starts stacking vertically, so the 'Webpage' shoots below 'My First' etc and the righthand side image shoots down and left below everything.

How do I make it so everything keeps it's aspect ratio as the browser window decreases in size? I don't want them to be a fixed size with any size window, I want them to decrease in size with the window whilst holding their position and aspect ratio.

I hope that makes sense.

Thanks.

```css
body {
margin: 0;
background-color: black;

}

.banner {

}


.banner-photo1 {
height: 250px;
width: 10%;
display: inline-block;
border-radius: 50%; 
margin-top: 6%;
margin-left: 2%;
min-width: 10%;
}

.banner-photo2 {
height: 250px;
width: 10%;
display: inline-block;
border-radius: 50%;
margin-top: 6%;
margin-right: 2%;
min-width: 10%;
}
.banner-title  {
height: 50%;
width: 75%;
color: #9649CB;
display: inline-block;
background-color: black;
margin-right: 0;

}

.banner h1 {

font-size: 150px;
padding: 0; 
margin-top: 0;
text-align: center;
margin-bottom: 0;
}
.banner-title h2 {
font-size: 60px;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 0;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.banner-title p {
text-align: center;
margin-top: 0;
font-size: 40px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Sample Website</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="banner">
            <img class="banner-photo1" 
    src="https://www.startuptalks.in/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/HTML.jpg">
            
            <div class="banner-title">
              <h1>My First Webpage</h1>
              <h2>Made With HTML & CSS</h2>
              <p>This Is A Sample Header</p>
            </div>
            
            <img class="banner-photo2" 
    src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphics-
    vibe/developer/256/css-icon.png">
            
        </div>  
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because when you use % for an element, you are actually setting this element to cover a percentage of the container it is inside.

So to get that fixed you can use min-width: number px;

You would be doing yourself a favor if you learn Bootstrap as it saves time in my experience 
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/

Answer (score 1):

### Responsive web development

It is called responsive because of your website response differently to different kind of screen sizes.

To keep it dynamic within different window sizes, e.g. desktop, mobile, you can use `@media`.

You can read more of it from w3school. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Basically, we are setting up different styles for different windows. Take an example, for a mobile phone, we do not want it to be too massive, but simply readable and does not strain the eyes. Thus we set the condition:

"If the size is less than so and so, reduce the font size to X. Maybe add some other extra features while you're into it."

Here is a solution for you:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    /* For mobile phones: */

    .banner-title {
      width: 60% !important;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .banner-title h1{
        font-size: 60px !important;
        padding: 0; 
        margin-top: 0;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .banner-photo1 {
      width: 20%;
      height: auto !important;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .banner-photo2 {
      width: 20%;
      height: auto !important;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8a8pLsfz/

To avoid stretching of the images, I suggest you set the condition of your image per one rule, e.g., only by width, or by height. Avoid both, unless your fixing it such as 40px by 40px;

Puting condition such as percentage % width and pixel px height will tear it apart because of different screen sizes.

### Making use of grid

One good thing for you to know is how to measure the width of the screen using percentage:

[image]
[Image source from http://bootstrap-sass.happyfuncorp.com]

This concept is applied in Bootstrap which you could try, but it is good to see the code how they actually do it. Check out [BOOTSTRAP CSS](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.css) and CTRL + F `col-md-3` and see how they do it.

### Where to from here

You can check out how to develop a mobile responsive website at W3school

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

And later, you will understand how it is being used in bootstrap, and why bootstrap increases your work speed with a lot of useful styles.